# Laravel seems to ignore authorization callbacks in channels.php

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to make a broadcast to a channel, and I have ensured that the broadcast works. Now I want to make sure that the channel is private and only authorized users can listen to it. Now according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks), I can do this by creating authorization callbacks and assigning for that channel and so I did, I created a Channel class with the `php artisan make:channel` command and assigned the channel class in the `routes/channel.php` as follows.

```
Broadcast::channel('private-admin.notifications.orders', OrderChannel::class);
```

The contents of the channel class are as follows.

```
class OrderChannel
{
    /**
     * Create a new channel instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate the user's access to the channel.
     */
    public function join(User $user): array|bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, the `join` method would always return false, this is intentional as I want to see what would have if an unauthorized user connects to the channel. I expect that the user won't be able to listen or subscribe to it but the user is still able to listen to the channel. I am sure of this since the code for the notification triggers and a notification is being displayed.

Things that I have done.

- Uncommented `BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php` and all of the contents of the `channels.php` are being return when I run the `php artisan channel:list` command.
- Cleared application cache.

I am using Laravel Websockets as my websocket server if that concerns anyone.

Am I doing something wrong or missing out on something?

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around for some time after posting this question. I found out that my custom authentication endpoint for broadcasting which is available through `/custom/broadcasting/auth` will always authenticate the user no matter what, a code snippet is as follows.

```
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\App;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Pusher\Pusher;

class AuthenticateDashboard
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Find the app by using the header
         * and then reconstruct the PusherBroadcaster
         * using our own app selection.
         */
        $app = App::findById($request->header('x-app-id'));

        $broadcaster = new PusherBroadcaster(new Pusher(
            $app->key,
            $app->secret,
            $app->id,
            []
        ));

        /*
         * Since the dashboard itself is already secured by the
         * Authorize middleware, we can trust all channel
         * authentication requests in here.
         */
        return $broadcaster->validAuthenticationResponse($request, []);
    }
}
```

It is a 1:1 copy of the default authentication method for laravel websockets which is available through `laravel-websockets/auth`

I did not know that the `validAuthenticationResponse()` method would always authenticate the request and I had to use the default authentication endpoint provided by laravel which is available through `broadcasting/auth`. I had to configure the endpoint a bit since it is not accepting my requests. I had to provide a custom authenticator method through Laravel Echo for it accept the requests.

My `Broadcast::routes` is as follows, this allows my frontend to have a successful requests to the authentication endpoint

```
Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'web']]);
```

With that being said, I am now using the default authentication endpoint provided by laravel which is the `broadcasting/auth` endpoint but with my configuration it is now `api/broadcasting/auth`.

Broadcasting no longer ignores my `channels.php` and is now working completely fine. It is just misconfiguration on my end.

Comment: I have added more information about the solution that I came up with shortly after posting this question.